# How to get person mobile number in google plus login in android

Tags: android

I want to obtain mobile number of logged in User in my app when user has logged in using google plus login.
In my app google plus login returns only username, user info and user's email address.

here is my code

```
    Person signedInUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (signedInUser != null)
    {
        if (signedInUser.hasDisplayName())
        {
            String userName = signedInUser.getDisplayName();

        }

        if (signedInUser.hasTagline())
        {
            String tagLine = signedInUser.getTagline();

        }

        if (signedInUser.hasAboutMe())
        {
            String aboutMe = signedInUser.getAboutMe();

        }

        if (signedInUser.hasBirthday())
        {
            String birthday = signedInUser.getBirthday();

        }

        if (signedInUser.hasCurrentLocation())
        {
            String userLocation = signedInUser.getCurrentLocation();

        }

        String userEmail = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Comment: AFAIK you cannot get phone number from Google plus 
Check this
https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people

Comment: You can't, read here https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount

Comment: got my answer thanks @Ajit and Heshan

Comment: It would be nice if you had shared your "answer"